# PerfectlySoft Perfect-HTTPServer: ~HTTP2Client.startReadThread

Tags: swift3

I'm using PerfectlySoft HTTPServer and from time to time (I assume when making (too?) many calls) I see

```
~HTTP2Client.startReadThread
```

in the logs and from there on the server seems slow/need some time to recover. Is there something to avoid this? Am I doing something wrong that this appears in the first place?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet @swalkner? Facing the same problem

Comment: Facing the same problem. Tried running a for loop in different threads, sync or async, and this happens every time